# How to use flask to stream a webcam video (paz) on the same screen as webapp?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, web-applications, webcam

Hi I have been working on some ML models and now I need to deploy them on a webapp so they are easily viewable to the client. I was working on paz for emotional detection and for paz my code works perfect. But when  try to put it up on flask, it comes on a new window. I want the webcam result to come on the same screen.
Here is my code for Paz:

```
import argparse
from paz.backend.camera import VideoPlayer
from paz.backend.camera import Camera
from paz.pipelines import DetectMiniXceptionFER


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Real-time face classifier')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--camera_id', type=int, default=0,
                                    help='Camera device ID')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--offset', type=float, default=0.1,
                                    help='Scaled offset to be added to bounding boxes')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    pipeline = DetectMiniXceptionFER([args.offset, args.offset])
    camera = Camera(args.camera_id)
    player = VideoPlayer((640, 480), pipeline, camera)
    player.run()
    player.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `pipeline` as a function:

```
from paz.backed.image import load_image

my_image = load_image('my_image.png')

results = pipeline(my_image)
```

Here`results` is a dictionary containing the image with the drawn inferences as well as the predictions, i.e.

```
my_image_with_drawn_predictions = results['image']
```

When using `pipeline` as a normal function you can write your client without the `VideoPlayer` class.

In case you want to visualize the image in the client you can use the internal functions:

```
from paz.backend.image import show_image

show_image(my_image_with_drawn_predictions)
```